# Polymer- using custom element in other projects like angular and Java jsp

Tags: polymer

I am trying to create custom form element which I am trying to reuse in other applications developed in angular and jsp page of Java

my-element.js:

```
    class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
      // This gets called when the HTML parser sees your tag
      constructor() {
        super(); // always call super() first in the ctor.
        this.msg = 'Hello, World!';
      }
      // Called when your element is inserted in the DOM or
      // immediately after the constructor if it’s already in the DOM
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="container">
        <label><b>Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

       <label><b>Age</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Age" name="age" required>


        <div class="clearfix">
          <button type="button"  class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>`;
      }
    }
    // This registers your new tag and associates it with your class
    window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

my-element.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <script src="my-element.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="import" href="add-form.html"> -->

</head>
<body>
<my-element></my-element>

</body>
</html>
```

Two issues I am struggling with now are below

1.Can i incude both the files as below to my angular and java jsp page and use custom tag to work?

```
<link rel="import" href="my-element.html">
<script src="my-element.js"></script>

 <my-element></my-element>
```

2. I am trying to pass below json object as an attribute to custom form element and trying to render custom form elements

[
      {
        "name":"Name",
        "type":"text",
        "size":"20",
        "readyOnly": false,
        "validateFunction":"onlyText"
      },
      {
        "name":"Age",
        "type":"number",
        "size":"3",
        "readyOnly": false,
        "validateFunction":"onlyNumber"
      }
    ]

I tried using below way to inject json data to custom element to render form elements based on json but no luck and there are no console errors

```
<my-element form-data="{{data}}"></my-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

ad 1) yes you can use your element with every server system you would like. It's "just html" that the beauty in it :)

ad 2)
HTMLElement won't do anything automatically. So if you wish to access your json you will have to do something like this

```
<my-element form-data="{'name': 'Name', 'type': 'text'}""></my-element>

connectedCallback() {
  let rawData = this.getAttribute('form-data');
  let jsonData = JSON.parse(rawData.replace(/'/g, '"'));
}
```

Notice that in the form-data json there are ' instead of ". So we have to replace them before using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I created plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/cPMeMCE0F5jDEMqLEaJ1 and getting below error -  Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).connectedCallback is not a function
    at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (my-element.js:10)

Comment: oh yeah sorry `HTMLElement` does not have a connectedCallback itself... (I'm just used to call it as you should if you are extending Polymer.Element) [I edited the answer]

Comment: thanks @dakmoR, it works but one problem , I am seeing is passing json variable to form-data attribute like form-data="jsonVariable" instead of passing JSON object

Comment: so how and where is your data available? if it's available within jsp you will most likely use it as I wrote before...
If you have the data within js then it depends on how it's defined... so more context is needed to give an answer...

Comment: data is coming from rest API service in json format

Comment: but how do you want to get it? usually apis have their own domain so you can't get them with ajax (because of cors)... so you would have to do it with jsp and then take the json and provide it as written before...
or do you plan to provide a server proxy on the some domain then you could just use a fetch inside your my-element (passing the value like that is not ne actually needed then)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is using a web component as opposed to a polymer component. The native web component API does not include data binding, although angular and polymer both do (but implemented in different ways).

Native web components and polymer components can be used with Angular as well as other frameworks.

Depending on whether you are using Angular.js(1) or Angular(2+), setting up the data object to be passed into the DOM will vary, but in general the data should be "set up" so to speak in the JS and passed into the DOM. Otherwise as @daKmoR said, the data would need to be declared as he did in his example.

There are packages that assist in implementing data 2-way binding between polymer's data bindings and angulars bindings if that is needed.

Trey